# Webgl2 passing attribute meaning

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm studying three.js and going through the documentation.
I don't get the meaning of the following description, can anyone help me?

> Since you are manually creating the WebGL 2 rendering context, you
>   also have to pass in all necessary context attributes. Note: It's not
>   possible to modify these attributes after the context has been
>   created, so passing them to the WebGLRenderer won't have any effect.

```
var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
var context = canvas.getContext( 'webgl2', { alpha: false } );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas, context: context } );
```

Comment: It's talking about the second argument of `canvas.getContext()`. You can find the list of attributes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you are creating `WebGLRenderer` and passing in the GL context, rather than letting the `WebGLRenderer` constructor create it for you.

This means that YOU are creating the context. In your case, the [`WebGL2RenderingContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext). When you create the context in this way, you need to supply all of the options during the `getContext` call. Passing GL options into the `WebGLRenderer` constructor **will not alter the context after-the-fact.**

Consider this:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
var context = canvas.getContext( 'webgl2', { alpha: false } );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas, context: context, alpha: true } );
```

On the last line, passing `alpha: true` will have absolutely no effect, because the previous line got the context (that you're giving to `WebGLRenderer` using `alpha: false`.